# R markdown- The sample file successfully knits to PDF, but my file fails

Tags: r, r-markdown, tinytex

Firstly, to give you some background,the conversion to PDF was successful on my PC, and an error occurred when I checked the operation on another person's PC. So there is no flaw in the program, in my opinion. The following is about checking the operation on another person's PC.

The sample file generated from File→new file→r markdown successfully knits to PDF, but my file fails to do so.(Authors and titles are in Japanese.)
It succeeds in the sample file, so I think the environment is ready.
The versions are the latest for both R and Rstudio, and I have tried the methods described in https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging.

I don't know what else to do.
Please help me.

yaml header

```
---
title: ''
documentclass: bxjsarticle
mainfont: Meiryo UI
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    number_sections: yes
monofont: Meiryo UI
classoption: xelatex,ja=standard
---
```

Error Code:

【Console】

```
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01) -- "Bird Hippie"
Copyright (C) 2021 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
 
R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.
 
R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.
 
Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.
 
> 
> install.packages("tinytex")
Install the package in 'C:/Users/81907/Documents/R/win-library/4.1 
(since 'lib' is not specified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/tinytex_0.35.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 126495 bytes (123 KB)
downloaded 123 KB
 
package ‘tinytex’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
 
The downloaded binary packages are in
C:\Users\81907\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpIXi0jR\downloaded_packages
> tinytex::install_tinytex()
trying URL 'https://yihui.org/tinytex/TinyTeX-1.zip'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 104711092 bytes (99.9 MB)
downloaded 99.9 MB
 
3 files have been copied
1 file has been copied.
Running fc-cache -v -r
tlmgr.pl: setting texmf max_print_line to 10000 (in C:/Users/81907/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf.cnf)
tlmgr install adobemapping arphic beamer bxjscls cjkcjkpunct cns ctablestack ctex everyhook fandol fonts-tlwgfp garuda-c90 haranoaji latex-base-dev latex-firstaid-dev luatexbase luatexja mptopdf ms norasi-c90 pgf platexplatex-tools ptex ptex-base ptex-fonts svn-prov translator ttfutils uhc ulem uplatex uptex uptex-base uptex-fonts wadalab xcjk2uni xecjk xpinyin zhmetrics zhmetrics-uptex zhnumber zxjatype
tlmgr.pl: package repository https://ftp.kddilabs.jp/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
[1/51, ??:??/??:??] install: adobemapping [2120k]
[2/51, 00:01/00:51] install: arphic [26742k]
[3/51, 00:06/00:22] install: beamer [163k]
[4/51, 00:07/00:26] install: bxjscls [33k]
[5/51, 00:08/00:30] install: cjk [58k]
[6/51, 00:08/00:30] install: cjkpunct [4k]
[7/51, 00:09/00:34] install: cns [2916k]
[8/51, 00:11/00:37] install: ctablestack [2k]
[9/51, 00:12/00:41] install: ctex [128k]
[10/51, 00:12/00:41] install: everyhook [3k]
[11/51, 00:13/00:44] install: fandol [21077k]
[12/51, 00:17/00:35] install: fonts-tlwg [4915k]
[13/51, 00:19/00:35] install: fp [19k]
[14/51, 00:19/00:35] install: garuda-c90 [4k]
[15/51, 00:20/00:37] install: haranoaji [25287k]
[16/51, 00:28/00:36] install: latex-base-dev [216k]
[17/51, 00:29/00:38] install: latex-firstaid-dev [4k]
[18/51, 00:29/00:38] install: luatexbase [4k]
[19/51, 00:30/00:39] install: luatexja [187k]
[20/51, 00:31/00:40] install: mptopdf.win32 [1k]
[21/51, 00:31/00:40] install: mptopdf [38k]
[22/51, 00:32/00:41] install: ms [3k]
[23/51, 00:32/00:41] install: norasi-c90 [9k]
[24/51, 00:33/00:43] install: pgf [701k]
[25/51, 00:34/00:44] install: platex.win32 [1k]
[26/51, 00:35/00:45] install: platex [41k]
[27/51, 00:35/00:45] install: platex-tools [9k]
[28/51, 00:36/00:46] install: ptex.win32 [1353k]
[29/51, 00:37/00:47] install: ptex [1k]
[30/51, 00:38/00:48] install: ptex-base [10k]
[31/51, 00:38/00:48] install: ptex-fonts [14k]
[32/51, 00:39/00:49] install: svn-prov [3k]
[33/51, 00:40/00:51] install: translator [28k]
[34/51, 00:40/00:51] install: ttfutils.win32 [329k]
[35/51, 00:41/00:52] install: ttfutils [107k]
[36/51, 00:41/00:52] install: uhc [3516k]
[37/51, 00:45/00:55] install: ulem [7k]
[38/51, 00:46/00:56] install: uplatex.win32 [1k]
[39/51, 00:46/00:56] install: uplatex [15k]
[40/51, 00:47/00:57] install: uptex.win32 [1813k]
[41/51, 00:49/00:58] install: uptex [1k]
[42/51, 00:49/00:58] install: uptex-base [10k]
[43/51, 00:50/00:59] install: uptex-fonts [166k]
[44/51, 00:50/00:59] install: wadalab [17357k]
[45/51, 00:54/00:54] install: xcjk2uni [196k]
[46/51, 00:55/00:55] install: xecjk [216k]
[47/51, 00:56/00:56] install: xpinyin [197k]
[48/51, 00:57/00:57] install: zhmetrics [59k]
[49/51, 01:02/01:02] install: zhmetrics-uptex [31k]
[50/51, 01:03/01:03] install: zhnumber [8k]
[51/51, 01:03/01:03] install: zxjatype [9k]
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
running updmap-sys ...
done running updmap-sys.
regenerating fmtutil.cnf in C:/Users/81907/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist
running fmtutil-sys --byengine euptex --no-error-if-no-format --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\81907\AppData\Local\Temp\oruuLVMDvD\ljHqQ7zPbc ...
 OK: euptex.fmt/euptex uplatex-dev.fmt/euptexuplatex.fmt/euptex
running fmtutil-sys --byengine eptex --no-error-if-no-format --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\81907\AppData\Local\Temp\oruuLVMDvD\ljHqQ7zPbc ...
 OK: euptex.fmt/euptex uplatex-dev.fmt/euptexuplatex.fmt/euptex eptex.fmt/eptex platex-dev.fmt/eptexplatex.fmt/eptex
running fmtutil-sys --byengine ptex --no-error-if-no-format --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\81907\AppData\Local\Temp\oruuLVMDvD\ljHqQ7zPbc ...
 OK: euptex.fmt/euptex uplatex-dev.fmt/euptexuplatex.fmt/euptex eptex.fmt/eptex platex-dev.fmt/eptexplatex.fmt/eptex ptex.fmt/ptex
running fmtutil-sys --byengine uptex --no-error-if-no-format --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\81907\AppData\Local\Temp\oruuLVMDvD\ljHqQ7zPbc ...
 OK: euptex.fmt/euptex uplatex-dev.fmt/euptexuplatex.fmt/euptex eptex.fmt/eptex platex-dev.fmt/eptexplatex.fmt/eptex ptex.fmt/ptex uptex.fmt/uptex
running fmtutil-sys --byfmt mptopdf --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\81907\AppData\Local\Temp\oruuLVMDvD\ljHqQ7zPbc ...
 OK: euptex.fmt/euptex uplatex-dev.fmt/euptexuplatex.fmt/euptex eptex.fmt/eptex platex-dev.fmt/eptexplatex.fmt/eptex ptex.fmt/ptex uptex.fmt/uptexmptopdf.fmt/pdftex
tlmgr.pl: package log updated: C:/Users/81907/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
tlmgr.pl: command log updated: C:/Users/81907/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr-commands.log
> update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)
Warning: package 'Matrix' in library 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.2/library' will not be updated
 
 There is a binary version available, but the source version is the latter.:
      binary source needs_compilation
Matrix  1.3-4  1.4-0              TRUE
 
 Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/digest_0.6.29.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 266591 bytes (260 KB)
downloaded 260 KB
 
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/Matrix_1.3-4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 4653247 bytes (4.4 MB)
downloaded 4.4 MB
 
package ‘digest’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package ‘digest’
Warning: restored ‘digest’
package ‘Matrix’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
 
The downloaded binary packages are in
C:\Users\81907\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpIXi0jR\downloaded_packages
Warning message:
In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
 problem copying C:\Users\81907\Documents\R\win-library\4.1\00LOCK\digest\libs\x64\digest.dll to C:\Users\81907\Documents\R\win-library\4.1\digest\libs\x64\digest.dll: Permission denied
> tinytex::tlmgr_update()
tlmgr update --all --self
 
 
 
【After the knit button】
processing file: myfile.Rmd
 |.......................                                               |  33%
 ordinary text without R code
 
 |...............................................                       |  67%
label: unnamed-chunk-1 (with options) 
List of 10
$ echo      : logi FALSE
$ error     : logi FALSE 
$ fig.height: num 10
$ fig.width : num 8
$ message   : logi FALSE
$ warning   : logi FALSE 
$ comment   : chr ""
$ dpi       : num 720
$ out.height: chr "150%"
$ out.width : chr "110%"
 
 
Add the following package: 'dplyr' 
 
The following objects are masked from 'package:stats': 
 
    filter, lag 
 
The following objects are masked from 'package:base': 
 
    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union 
 
 |......................................................................| 100%
 ordinary text without R code
 
 
"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS myfile.knit.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output myfile.tex --lua-filter "C:\Users\81907\Documents\R\win-library\4.1\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "C:\Users\81907\Documents\R\win-library\4.1\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\latex-div.lua" --self-contained --number-sections --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine xelatex --variable graphics 
output file: myfile.knit.md
 
error: LaTeX failed to compile myfile.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. 
Execution has been stopped.
```

Comment: Hi. Can you edit your question please to add a **small** reproducible example of a failing script please; maybe be enough for the example to just include the yaml header?

Comment: Added yaml header @user20650

Comment: Thanks. Can you also confirm that just executing just the header fails. If it does, could you also show the specific error in that instance e.g. without all the install packages / tinytex messages.

Comment: Even when running only the yaml header, the conversion to PDF was successful.
To give you some background, the conversion to PDF was successful on my PC, and an error occurred when I checked the operation on another person's PC.So there is no flaw in the program, in my opinion. @user20650